# How to find what operations/permissions my Azure Service Principal needs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-rbac

I'm trying to lock down my Azure service principals with minimum permissions.  This can be done by [creating custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles#actions).  But in defining custom roles, how do I know what actions are required for a given task?  For example, if an automation account needs to runs several *AzureRm* cmdlets in a powershell script (`Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret`, `New-AzureRmContainerGroup`, `Get-AzureRmContext`, etc.), how do I find out which "Actions" each of those commands performs?

`Get-AzureRMProviderOperation *` lists all available Actions (currently rendering a list of 2969--a slightly overwhelming number to sort through).  How do I determine which of those I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if you want to use Azure automation account to run runbook command
 `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret`, we should give that SP permissions like:

`Microsoft Authorization`:
[image]
`Microsoft Automation`: `Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks/read`

`Microsoft.KeyVault` need those permissions:

```
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read 
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/read
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies/write
```

Normally, we can setup roles for each provider. For example, `Microsoft.KeyVault`, we want SP can update key vault or read secrets, we can add `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write` and `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/read` and `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read`.

```
PS C:\Users\jason> Get-AzureRmProviderOperation * | ?{ $_.ProviderNamespace -eq 'Microsoft Key Vault' } | select Operation, OperationName

Operation                                               OperationName
---------                                               -------------
Microsoft.KeyVault/register/action                      Register Subscription
Microsoft.KeyVault/unregister/action                    Unregister Subscription
Microsoft.KeyVault/hsmPools/read                        View HSM pool
Microsoft.KeyVault/hsmPools/write                       Create or Update HSM pool
Microsoft.KeyVault/hsmPools/delete                      Delete HSM pool
Microsoft.KeyVault/hsmPools/joinVault/action            Join KeyVault to HSM pool
Microsoft.KeyVault/checkNameAvailability/read           Check Name Availability
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read                          View Key Vault
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write                         Update Key Vault
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/delete                        Delete Key Vault
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action                 Use Vault for Azure Deployments
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/read                  View Secret Properties
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/write                 Update Secret
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies/write          Update Access Policy
Microsoft.KeyVault/operations/read                      Available Key Vault Operations
Microsoft.KeyVault/deletedVaults/read                   View Soft Deleted Vaults
Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/operationResults/read      Check Operation Result
Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/read         View Soft Deleted Key Vault
Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action Purge Soft Deleted Key Vault
```

After that completed, we can assign this role to your SP which you want to `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret`. We can assign many roles to one SP.

**Note**:

Every Service principal need `Microsoft Authorization` permission, or this SP will not login to Azure.

Normally, Azure PowerShell command `Get` need read permission, `New`, `set` and `Update` need write permission.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Is it not necessary to assign the SP to the Key Vault Access Policies? :)

Comment: @juunas thank you, you are right, we still need  associate key vault access policy to the SP.

Comment: Yeah, the roles in IAM give it access to the ARM API side of KeyVault, but to access the KeyVault API I guess it requires the access policy.

Comment: Thanks @JasonYe-MSFT.  I have a few follow up questions: 1) Can I grant access to a child resource (Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/read) without giving access to the parent resource (Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read)? 2) In the Microsoft Authorization namespace, I see 25 different operations.  Which of those does a service principal need just to log in and run a simple command (assuming it already has other permissions it needs)?  3) in some places i see Microsoft.xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/action.  What is /action compared to /* ?

Comment: @jschmitter 1)we can't grant access to a child resource without giving access to the parent resource.  2)  we can grant all read permission to SP to login Azure, `Microsoft.Authorization/*/read`. 3)No, `/action` like `Microsoft.KeyVault/register/action`, or `Microsoft.KeyVault/unregister/action`, not `/*`, just one operation of that.

Comment: @jschmitter Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.